# Setting variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a posibility to set variables dynamically?

My code looks like this. The if gets true but how do I (if possible) set the variable to true dynamically?

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import {forEach} from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  menuContentSize = false;
  menuContentBackground = false;
  menuContentImages = false;
  menuContentText = false;
  menuContentFrame = false;

  menuOptions: string[] = ['menuContentSize',
    'menuContentBackground',
    'menuContentImages',
    'menuContentText',
    'menuContentFrame'];


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  menuOptionSelected(event){
    this.menuOptions.forEach(function(element){
      if(element == event){
        // Set name of element(variable) to true
        // In my dreamworld this.element = true; will be e.g. this.menuContentSize = true;
      }

    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.menuOptions.forEach(function(element){
```

needs to be

```
this.menuOptions.forEach((element) => {
```

if you want to use `this` to reference to the current component instance

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

I'm not sure about the rest of your question.

I guess what you want is

```
this[element] = true;
```

which sets `this.menuContentSize` to `true` if `element` holds the string value `'menuContentSize'`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Will set to correct answer when time span is meet.